# Disconnection when attempting ajax request. Cypress

Tags: ajax, post, request, cypress

I am quite new to automated testing (up until recently I'v been a manual tester) and I've recently taken up Cypress.

I've been trying to select an item from a drop down list. After selecting one item the next drop-down list should occur under. A 'POST' request should be made (as in the gif bellow).

[browser behaviour during manual testing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3KJd.gif)

When this test case is runned in Cypress after selecting an item from the first drop-down list I am getting an alert in my native language about a temporary lack of internet connection and no 'POST' request is being made.

Below I provide a code snippet:

```
cy.intercept('POST', 'https://sprzedajemy.pl/new-offer-manager/ajax-get-category-selectors-box/tmp_id/-1647426073?category_id=id_2').as('authenticate')

cy.get(".theButton.theButtonRed.theButtonAdd").click({ force: true });

cy.pause();

cy.get("#category_selector_5>:nth-child(" + id + ")").then(function ($elem) {

   cy.get("#category_selector_5").select($elem.text(),{ force: true });

   cy.wait('@authenticate').its('response.statusCode').should('eq', 200)

});
```

[error message, it's in Polish, it means basically: "No internet connection. Please try again later. Sorry for the inconvenience](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1gcX0.png)

[network tab throughout the whole test case execution in Cypress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28FG7.gif)

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the complete error message? As well as the corresponding HTML?

Comment: Can you check the Network tab to verify a POST request was not sent?

Comment: @agoff What do you mean exactly by coressponding HTML?  The whole html code of the page at the moment of the error's occurence? By the way I've added some new images to the post.

Comment: The HTML that you are interacting with in your Cypress test would be ideal. But looking at your test run, it looks like the Cookie popup is probably blocking you from actually interacting with the element. If you add something to dismiss that popup before attempting to click the element, does it work as expected?

Comment: The Cookie popup is awkward but it doesn't affect the test case. It pop ups because it's a production environment that every web user can access. I also ran the test case  in a development instance (no cookie pop up)  and the same error occured. The whole HTML is to big to be pasted. I've uploaded the html file here: https://ufile.io/s14j4eyy. It's safe.

Answer (score 0):

Matching urls is a bit of a black art, but I think the problem is the `-1647426073` portion of the POST url.

Not sure if it's the `-` or the lack of alpha chars in that section, but it breaks the matching.

But it can be wildcarded to make it work.

I'm not getting a disconnection, so maybe that's another issue.

The following summarizes working and not-working `cy.intercept()`. I'm using the longer form of routeMatcher for convenience.

```js
const routeMatcher = {
  method: 'POST',

  // url: '/new-offer-manager/ajax-get-category-selectors-box/tmp_id/-1647426073?category_id=id_2',  //no
  // url: '/new-offer-manager/ajax-get-category-selectors-box/tmp_id/*?category_id=id_2', //yes
  // url: '**/ajax-get-category-selectors-box/tmp_id/*?category_id=id_2', //yes
  // url: '**/tmp_id/*?category_id=id_2',  //yes

  // path: '/new-offer-manager/ajax-get-category-selectors-box/tmp_id/-1647426073?category_id=id_2',  //no
  // path: '/new-offer-manager/ajax-get-category-selectors-box/tmp_id/*?category_id=id_2',  //yes
  // path: '**/tmp_id/*?category_id=id_2',  //yes

  // pathname: '/new-offer-manager/ajax-get-category-selectors-box/tmp_id/-1647426073',  //no
  // pathname: '/new-offer-manager/ajax-get-category-selectors-box/tmp_id/*',  //yes
  // pathname: '**/tmp_id/*',  //yes
  // query: {
  //   category_id: 'id_2'
  // }
}

cy.intercept(routeMatcher).as('authenticate')
```

**Some notes**

- the base url `https://sprzedajemy.pl` is assumed by Cypress so you can leave it out
- the `*` wildcard must replace the whole segment (part between `\` and `?`), so `/*?category_id=id_2` but not `/*1647426073?category_id=id_2`
- you can shorten further by wildcarding the start of the url as per `**/tmp_id/*`
- `pathname:` option works without the query portion, or you can add the query option separately to make a stronger match
- you can leave out the URL altogether and add a `{times:1}` to catch only that single POST request.

  ```js
  const routeMatcher = {
    method: 'POST',
    times: 1
  }
  cy.intercept(routeMatcher).as('authenticate')
  ```

---

**Asserting the 2nd dropdown**

If you assert the contents of the 2nd dropdown, there is no need to wait for the POST intercept (unless you specifically want to check it occurs)

```js
cy.get('#category_selector_5').select('Motoryzacja')
cy.get('#category_selector_2 option').should('have.length', 16)  // passes
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for the answer. "I'm not getting a disconnection, so maybe that's another issue." - so that mean's that after selecting an item from the first drop-down list you're getting the html response and the second drop-down list is getting loaded?

Comment: I didn't check that far, just found the working intercept.

Comment: If I add `cy.get('#category_selector_2').find('option').should('have.length', 16)` it passes.

Comment: In fact, with that command you can remove the intercept and the `cy.wait('@authenticate')`